# How is SNR (Signal-to-Noise-Ratio) related to receiver power?

Tags: rf, wireless, signal, communication

If I have the instantaneous SNR (of the receiver) but no other information, and I am interested in the instantaneous *Power<sub>received</sub>*, is there any relationship between these two terms?

Comment: In case of wireless, the band noise is Vrms=sqrt(4*k*T*B), and from this you can estimate the carrier power, if modulation type is known.
If the measure is taken after the tuner unit, then add the tuner noise figure as well.

Answer (score 1):

SNR is the ratio of signal to noise. Total power would be noise power + signal power. Note that if these powers are in dB, you add them according to the formula given by

$$10*log_{10}(10^{S/10}+10^{N/10}) dB$$

since these powers are uncorrelated.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't relate - SNR is a ratio - if you had an amplifier and the gain was 50 would you know anything about the input level? No you wouldn't because it's a ratio and not an absolute value.